# How to use robocopy to copy folders and keep the modified date in windows server

Tags: window

I tried this command in windows server 2008

```
robocopy "aaa\" bbb\ /copy:datsou /dcopy:t /MIR
```

Only file's modified date keep, foler's date is always now.
I also tried in my Windows 10, notebook.
That command works, the new folder's date is the same as the original.

This also work in Win 10

```
robocopy "aaa\" bbb\ /MIR /dcopy:t
```

Why not work in server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

you should see this maybe this can solve your problem.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/83fd1d99-799f-4c30-b148-586b1cc7639d/keeping-folder-modified-date-when-using-robocopy?forum=winservergen

Comment: At the end of that post now says /dcopy:t, which I already used.